# Meteor's clientside technology stack

Tags: meteor

I'm thinking of adopting Meteor for my hobby project and I'm wondering something.

On one or two websites that were comparing various frameworks listed Meteor as one having both client and server libraries (a better term could be used here, but I can't think of one!).

So my question is... 
Where can I find more info about this client library and its capabilities? 
Can I drop the default library (whatever it may be) for something like Knockout? Do I need or want to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meteor has a *database everywhere* approach which means that you can use the same interface for accessing your data on both client and server.  (i.e. MyCollection.find() would do a find whether you're on client or server.

As for client side libraries, meteor supports adding packages such as other templating engines like [meteor-knockout](https://github.com/bevanhunt/meteor-knockout).  As well meteor comes with the Handlebars templating engine, which is what is used in the docs.  See [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#templates)

In general, if you want to know anything about Meteor, the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com) are the best place to go.